# How to know when all Controls' Handles on a Windows Form have been created?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

I have a race condition in my Windows Form at startup.  I think I've identified the problem, but am not sure of the best/easiest way to solve it.

- The Form has a worker thread that listens on the network for messages from other services.  This worker thread activates at "startup" and opens a socket to begin listening.  Depending on the contents of the messages received, Controls on the Form can be manipulated (for example, enable a button)
- Occasionally, I'll get an InvalidOperationException on startup that traces back to this worker thread:

> `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` cannot be called on a window handle until the control has been created.

I've already worked through the CrossThreadException issues that come with a worker thread trying to manipulate Windows Controls created on the main thread (by using `.InvokeRequired` and `.Invoke`).  I've concluded there's a race condition here at startup, where this worker thread starts and begins receiving messages from the other services, and sometimes before the Handles for all the Controls on my form are created, it tries to manipulate one (enable a button, for example).  If that button handle is not yet created, I get the exception.

Things I've tried or considered trying:

1. In other SO questions, I was directed towards [this page from MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).  I had hopes that starting my worker thread in the `Form.Shown` event handler would solve the problem.  However, breaking in this event handler and examining the environment shows that `.IsHandleCreated` for a relevant button is `false`, so the problem is still potentially there.
2. Before opening the network socket in the worker thread, I could spinwait, looping through all the Controls in the Form and check their `.IsHandleCreated` property, but saw the only thing returned from `Form.Controls` are the Form's immediate children, so I would need some kind of recursion to check everything.
3. I can add an additional `.IsHandleCreated` check to all my functions that check for `.IsInvokeRequired`, but there's quite a few of them, and was hoping for something simpler.
4. Similar to 1, I can create a list of all the Controls that can be manipulated by network messages, and have the worker thread spinwait until all Handles are created before listening on the network.  Again, this seems clunky and high maintenance.

So my question, is there an easy/simple way to know when all the Controls on a form have their Handles created, after which I'll create this worker thread to begin listening for network traffic?  An event perhaps?  Or is this an X-Y problem and I should consider an entirely different approach?  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675771/wait-until-form-is-finished-loading) is related, but the accepted answer (1 above) is not going to solve my problem.

The basic setup is this:

```
// Program.cs
static void Main()
{
  ....
  MyForm form = new MyForm();
  Application.Run(form);
}
```

---

```
// MyForm.cs
public MyForm()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  ...
  UDP_ReceiveInterface recvInterface = new UDP_ReceiveInterface(...);
}

private void MyForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  recvInterface.Activate();
}
```

---

```
// UDP_ReceiveInterface.cs
...
public void Activate()
{
  listenThread_ = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForPackets));
}

private void ListenForPackets()
{
  // opens up a socket with network info from a config file
}
```

I've tried moving the `UDP_ReceiveInterface.Activate()`function to different places... in MyForm constructor, in Program.cs after `form` is created, and as shown above, in the `MyForm_Shown` event handler.  The entire GUI is dominated by a TabControl, so all the controls are on one of six TabPages.

Comment: Controls, from Form.Load on, return `IsHandleCreated = false` if they're not visible. Or if you add them to a TabControl in a TabPage that is not shown, conditions like this. Which Controls have not created their handles yet in your scenario? Where is this worker thread run and what kind of thread is that? Can you post some code?

Comment: *Not visible* is referring to the `Visible` property set to `false`, not their bounds in relation to the Client Area.

Comment: @Jimi I don't (yet) have a comprehensive list of all the controls that could possibly be manipulated by network traffic, but the whole GUI is dominated by a TabControl, so the buttons I care about are on TabPages. I haven't thought much about visibility, should I explicitly command the TabPages to be visible? The worker thread actually exists in a UDP Receiver class, `listenThd = new Thread( ... );`. I've played with different places where this new thread is created. In my From constructor, in Program.cs after my Form is created, in the `Form.Shown` event handler...

Comment: You can force the creation of a Control's handle by retrieving it: `var h = button1.Handle;`. If `button1` is in a TabPage not visible when the Form is first shown, it will create the Handle nonetheless. You can do the same with a Control not visible.

Comment: @Jimi Interesting.. good to know. I may end up doing something like that. Some code is forthcoming... not sure it will be all that helpful tho.

Comment: Well you can also do something like `tabControl1.TabPages[1].Show();`, so you don't have to cycle all of its child Controls. Note that this won't move `TabPages[1]` to front: `TabPages[0]` will still be the one presented when the Form is shown.

Comment: @Jimi oh cool, I'll give that a try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221656/discussion-between-yano-and-jimi).

Comment: Every `Control` has a `HandleCreated` event. If you _really_ want to go that route, just subscribe to that event on every control and wait for all of them to raise the event. See duplicate. You do seem to have broader issues, but your question is stated too broadly to properly address them on Stack Overflow. If all you want is to be able to call `Control.Invoke()`, you can do that with the `Form` instance; it won't matter whether other control handles have been created. ...

Comment: ... Another strategy would be to give up on Winforms and use WPF, which eliminates both the issue of a control's window handle, as well as dealing with cross-thread access (when you use data binding, cross-thread access is handled automatically for you by the framework).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375750/what-are-the-side-affects-of-ensuring-every-control-created-has-a-handle-in-net and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442487/what-is-the-form-on-load-equivalent-for-controls

Comment: @Peter Duniho That doesn't answer the question or solve the problem. The OP is updating Controls from a worker thread. The issue is that most of these Controls are inside TabPages of a TabControl. The `HandleCreated` event or relative method won't say anything that is not already known. The event is also not raised, since the handle is not created at all when a Control is child of a TabPage that is not shown.

Comment: @Jimi: it answers the only _specific_ question the OP asked. Open-ended "what could possibly be wrong?" questions, especially those which lack a [mcve], are off-topic here, so there's no need to worry if they don't get answers. That said, I have in fact also explained to the OP that they don't need the handle to be created on every control; they can use the `Form` itself to call `Invoke()`, which obviates the entire issue (since that object's handle is known to be created).

Comment: @PeterDuniho I didn't ask "What could possibly be wrong?" I asked "Is there a way to know when all Controls on a form have their Handles created?" I also don't think this is a dupe of what's linked, but nevertheless thanks, what you've linked has been helpful, and I think the answer does speak to my question even tho a different question was asked. Don't think an MRE is feasible here, especially considering the race condition.

Comment: _"I didn't ask "What could possibly be wrong?" I asked "Is there a way to know when all Controls on a form have their Handles created?""_ -- that statement is half correct. The second part is correct, and the duplicate question answers exactly that. The question does, however, carry a lot more in it than just that, and that's what amounts to "what could possibly be wrong?" _"Don't think an MRE is feasible here, especially considering the race condition"_ -- the author of the question doesn't get to decide whether [mcve] is required; and the presence of a race condition in no way precludes one.

Comment: @Peter Duniho Of course you can Invoke/BeginInvoke the Form, still, those Controls' handles are not created yet, which could lead to unpredictable results in some cases. Anyway, the current issue is solved and the OP has some new information about this matter, I'm good with it.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I know what's wrong. I have a race condition between network data manipulating form controls and those controls (or their handles) perhaps not yet being created before that manipulation occurs. My solution was to ensure all these handles are created _before_ I even start listening on the network. I asked if there's a way to know when all these handles are created. An MRE would involve 2 processes and mostly be socket code, but sure, if that's particularly useful in answering my question, I can create one.

Comment: @Jimi: _"those Controls' handles are not created yet, which could lead to unpredictable results in some cases"_ -- such as? The fact is, controls are initialized in the call to `InitializeComponent()`, before handles are created. Any update to a control as a result of some background worker thread should be no different than whatever initialization might occur in the first place, and so would be no more harmful. And regardless of your concerns there, the _question_ has an answer in the duplicate.

Comment: @Peter Duniho  Some properties are initialized, still the handle is not created. There's a reason why you cannot invoke a Control that doesn't have a handle. Anyway, this question has already too many comments, a diamond will probably wipe it out.

Comment: @Jimi: _"There's a reason why you cannot invoke a Control that doesn't have a handle"_-- that's true. But it has nothing to do with whether you can access the control to update its properties. It's simply because without the handle, there's no way to post a message to the control's owning thread's message queue, since there is no owning thread yet. You can still access the control for other purposes, such as updating state according to whatever values need to be presented to the user.

Comment: @Peter Duniho [202](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,202)-[871](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,871)-[1475](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,1475)-[1544](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,1544)-[4515](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,4515).

Comment: @Peter Duniho Just some, only related to the base class. Not counting  `BeginUpdate()` / `EndUpdate()` methods and all `BeginUpdateInternal()` calls of derived Controls. All native methods that are not called when the handle is not created, the caching of text and ListControls items. You're right in that some base properties can be set/get even when the Control has not created its handle yet (this of course happens in `InitializeComponent()`). Can you predict when something will fail or *glitch out* instead? Since we, usually, work with Controls that do have a handle.

Comment: @Jimi: you're pretty funny. Posting a bunch of links completely irrelevant to the question of updating a control based on changes in the information being presented to the user. As if that helps.

Comment: @Peter Duniho I'm missing the funny part. That's relevant, since the OP is working with Controls that are not exactly *presented to the User*, that's one of the reasons why these Controls don't have a handle yet. Can you answer the question I asked in my previous comment, or not? You don't really need to answer it to me.

Comment: @Jimi: sure. I can predict that for every example of a call the OP wanted to make from `Control.Invoke()`, it is perfectly safe to do so even if the control's handle has not yet been created. That's the only thing that matters. For example, [TextBoxBase.Text](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBoxBase.cs,1235). All Winforms controls follow this pattern for properties involved in the visual state of the control; the property can be accessed whether or not the handle is created.

Comment: @PeterDuniho _I can predict that for every example of a call the OP wanted to make from `Control.Invoke()`, it is perfectly safe to do so even if the control's handle has not yet been created._ That's clearly false, since I'm getting the exception. But I'll take the blame on that due to lack of code/MRE. It's just the "standard" `if(ctrl.InvokeRequired) Invoke(...) else performTheAction`. The exception says the handle isn't created yet so it cannot `Invoke`. Just nuke the question, you obviously want to. I already have my answer anyway, since no one answered in the affirmative.

Comment: A simple "No, there's no simple/easy way to determine if all form controls have their handles created." would've been easier than the pissing contest that ensued. This is probably an X-Y question anyway, or I'm going about this all wrong. Otherwise it would've been asked already. I'm surely not the first person using C# to write a GUI with a dedicated thread for receiving network data whose contents manipulate form controls. Anyway, thanks for the links, they were informative.

Comment: _"That's clearly false, since I'm getting the exception"_ -- wrong. The exception you are getting is specifically the call to `Invoke()` itself. That has _zero_ to do with whether, having successfully invoked back to the UI thread (e.g. using the form's `Invoke()` method, or capturing the synchronization context), you can then access the controls you need.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks a lot for the suggestion! Looping through each TabPage worked, although I'm paranoid and will probably go the recursive route of touching every control on the form. Would've made the most sense to UV you here, but since that's no longer possible, no worries, I got you elsewhere ;)